# ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR, even though query is correct

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm connecting to a mysql server and making a query. I keep getting a ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR : unknown column  in 'field list'

```
connection.query("SELECT ID FROM shorturl WHERE urlsource = '" + url + "'", function(error, rows, fields){
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
```

Comment: Does the following query run without error on MySQL: `SELECT ID FROM shorturl WHERE urlsource = 'some_url'` ?  By the way, you should parametrize your query, because as it stands now someone might be able to SQL inject you.

Comment: Yes it works on MySQL.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen How do I parametrize it?

Answer (score 0):

You should parameterize your query in Node.js:

```
connection.query('SELECT ID FROM shorturl WHERE urlsource = ?', [url], function (err, rows, fields) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

This hopefully will also resolve the current error you are seeing.